# JEST: SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token for css file

Tags: css, reactjs, testing, jestjs, babel-jest

This error occured for @ character in my css file import, for my react component while testing the component in jest

```
({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){@charset "UTF-8";
```

package.json test command

```
"test": "jest --config=jest.config.json tests/"
```

and css file is starts like this:

```
`@charset "UTF-8";

/*!
 * Bootstrap v5.1.0 (https://getbootstrap.com/)`
```

It's not a typescript project

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: i found the solution to it, just installed jest-stub and made followning changes as given in this git repo https://github.com/eddyerburgh/jest-transform-stub